# How to quickly convert planks to stones in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have these planks I want to convert them to bricks.

[image]

These planks are split into multiple segments, and I want each segment or two segments to be a stone, like the first two.

I did two bricks manually but it went way too slow.

Is there a quick key command to split these planks into bricks?

Answer (score 0):

In the *Transform Pivot Point* panel choose *Individual Origins*, select all, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Individual Faces*, then scale down the extruded faces:

[image]

Comment: cool. how did u know he wanted it to look like that? he did say though he made 2 bricks manually but i didn't see them in the pic.

Comment: I think he's talking about what we see on the top left of his image, no?

Comment: oh now i can see it. it was kinda subtle but i see what he means now. yeah your solution should work perfectly